# What is the use of [_secure => true] in controller redirect path argument in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, redirect, secure

Anyone can explain to me what is the use of [_secure => true] in controller redirect path arguments in Magento 2.

Comment: I traced it to here https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Url.php#L467-L469 but you're right.  Beyond that it's a bit of a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out it

Fundamentally it's a parameter which is set.  The getting and setting of the parameter does nothing more than set or get the value.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Url.php#L406-L415

However other functionality looks at the value

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Url.php#L307-L321

But in summary it's telling Magento to switch to the configured secure URL if it's configured.